# How do you know when to use tildes?

Tags: gramática

What are the grammatical rules for "tildes"? When do you know when and where to put them?

Comment: Note that we call what I think you mean accents in English _tilde_ is the Spanish. https://dle.rae.es/tilde?m=form also _acento_ in Spanish.

Comment: There's one tilde, ñ, but if this question is about *accents*, it's covered by [What are the accent placement rules in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/661/13538)

Comment: Tilde has just this meaning in English but in Spanish "tilde" is also an accent type. [Los acentos y las tildes](https://www.lenguaje.com/reglasV2/acentos.html)

Answer (score 1):

Las normas de acentuación en español son:

- Las palabras agudas llevan tilde cuando acaban en “n”, en “s” o vocal, aunque existen algunas excepciones (baúl, maíz, etc.).
- Las palabras llanas llevan tilde cuando no acaban en vocal, “n” o “s”.
- Las palabras esdrújulas y sobreesdrújulas se acentúan siempre.

Información obtenida de; [https://espanoleschool.com/es/como-acentuan-palabras-espanol/#:~:text=En%20este%20sentido%2C%20las%20normas,y%20sobreesdr%C3%BAjulas%20se%20acent%C3%BAan%20siempre](https://espanoleschool.com/es/como-acentuan-palabras-espanol/#:%7E:text=En%20este%20sentido%2C%20las%20normas,y%20sobreesdr%C3%BAjulas%20se%20acent%C3%BAan%20siempre).

---

Información en:

https://www.spanishskype.org/single-post/2015/02/19/reglas-b%C3%A1sicas-de-acentuaci%C3%B3n-basic-rules-for-stress-and-accent-marks-in-spanish

**Basic rules for stress and accent marks in Spanish**

[image]

---

Para ampliar contenido e información especifica;

https://www.rae.es/dpd/tilde#321

**Diccionario panhispánico de dudas**.

> tilde1. 1. Se llama tilde tanto al acento gráfico como al rasgo o
> trazo pequeño que forma parte de algunas letras, como la ç, la ñ, la
> t, etc. En ambos casos admite los dos géneros, aunque hoy se usa
> casi...

Comment: hay que hacer mención a las excepciones, por ej. cuando vs cuándo, más vs mas... o en caso de hiatos, entre otros

Comment: Hello Diego! I really appreciate your answer but can you please translate it in English? I am very new in Spanish and I can't understand what you are saying yet. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¡Hola! Piano Man, You can visit https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/661/what-are-the-accent-placement-rules-in-spanish or look this good video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXro8ngx07A