# Why does "violínes" take an accent on the "i" according to this sentence?

Tags: plurales, acentuación

Recently I was doing my homework and I saw the sentence:

"Así es cómo exactamente se llama el trabajo que nos transporta al mundo de las fugas, conciertos de violínes, Suites y Preludios."

The sentence prints "violínes" with an accent even though it is in plural. Most accents are usually dropped when a noun is made in plural. So, why does the above sentence not follow that rule?

Comment: Save your bounty. The example you found is simply wrong. "Violines" (without accent) follows the standard accentuation rules.

Comment: We already have a canonical answer about accentuation rules in Spanish https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/661/what-are-the-accent-placement-rules-in-spanish?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Violines does not have a "tilde". Your example is wrong.

> Most accents are usually dropped when a noun is made in plural

The use of tilde or not does not have anything to do with plurals. It is really simple:
Violines have the (sound) accent in the last minus one syllable: LI
The rule is that it only have tilde if the last syllable DO NOT finish with vowel or N,S.
In this case it ends with S, so it does not have a tilde

Answer (score 4):

"Así es cómo exactamente se llama el trabajo que nos transporta al mundo de las fugas, conciertos de **violines**, Suites y Preludios".

En el caso de que "violines" se encuentre con "tilde" en la segunda "i", se trataría de un **error** o como se suele decir, sería simplemente "**una falta ortográfica**" como tantas otras que a veces aparecen en libros y documentos escritos, solo se trataría de corregirla o saber que no esta bien.

- La palabra "violines", pronunciada con vocal tónica en la segunda "i" **no lleva tilde**, ya que las palabras llanas o graves acabadas en "n", "s" o "vocal" no llevan tilde.
- Las palabras llanas llevan tilde cuando no terminan en "-n", en "-s" o en "vocal".

La palabra correcta sería "**violines**", **sin tilde**.

**Otras causas de errores o despistes ortográficos**;

- Muchas veces los libros escritos en español son publicaciones que se realizan en el extranjero y las "faltas ortográficas" no son detectadas.
- También se encuentran en publicaciones escritas en inglés, que por desconocimiento o sin pretenderlo no atienden a las reglas de acentuación.
- Otras veces aquel que escribe piensa que como "**violín**" lleva tilde, por ser palabra aguda, acentuada por acabar en "n", "s", o "vocal", la palabra "violines", también debería llevar tilde "violínes", sin prestar atención a las reglas de acentuación.
- También se puede caer en la trampa de leer frases como por ejemplo "el **violín es** un tipo de instrumento..." y creer por error haber leído "**violínes**".

Algunos ejemplos de "**faltas u errores ortográficos**" con la palabra "violín" escrita en plural y acentuada "**violínes**";

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obsérvese en este último caso la palabra "violín" y "violínes", se aprecia que el que lo ha escrito piensa que son palabras que tienden a utilizar el mismo patrón, evidenciando que singular y plural de "**violín**" se escriben con  tilde.